# Windows 10 not using imported cert to decrypt EFS files

Tags: windows-10, certificate, efs

I encrypted some files with Windows's built-in EFS encryption, which involved creating a new EFS certificate and saving a backup of it somewhere. I recently swapped motherboards/re-imaged my PC and now cannot access the encrypted files, which is expected.

I re-imported my saved certificate using the correct password which worked successfully, but I still cannot access these files - getting various errors about permissions or decryption that aren't very specific.

Here is my current certificate store, I have created a new EFS cert and imported my old one:

[image: certmgr]

Here is the details of the cert matching the thumbprint of the cert that is allowed to access the file.

[image: thumbprint]

If I try and remove the checkbox for encrypting these files I get this error:

[image: Error]

Are there any steps I missed?

Comment: Why did you create a new certificate?

Comment: I had other things to encrypt, basically. I can try decrypting the files that was used for and then remove it - it doesn't seem likely to be the issue though.

Comment: removing the new certificate did not solve the issue. Windows does still seem to be using it even though it has been removed from my personal certificate store.